# Writing Junit Testcase for a default method in an Interface

Tags: java, junit

I am using Java 1.8 and using default method in Interface.
As we are targeting to write JUnit for all the methods we have I have a situation that need to write Junit for default method. Can somebody help me please to know whether we can achieve it.

My Interface is below.

```
 public interface DataFilter {

   default public TableInclusions parseYaml(String path) throws IOException {

    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(path);
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    yaml.setBeanAccess(BeanAccess.FIELD);
    return yaml.loadAs(resource.getInputStream(), TableInclusions.class);
   }

   public DBMSEvent filter(DBMSEvent jsonString) throws FilterException;

   public void setYaml(String path);
}
```

Should I need to write Junit for the method of the class which implements this Interface and uses this default method to test it?

Answer (score 5):

In your test you could do:

```
DataFilter dataFilter = new DataFilter() {
//Add no-op implementation for other methods
};
datafilter.parseYaml(testPath);
```

But looking add your interface I don't think you should have this default method at all. I think it would be better to inject a TableInstructorParser with this method in it. That would be better for your separation of concerns.

Comment: Hi Bob,Is there any other way to write with out extending is what I am trying to check.

Comment: Since this is an interface, it's actually implementing, not extending.
Not sure if you've realised this, but the suggestion is to to this within your test method (and not creating an explicit class for it)